# Who is the NYC block producer? How much eos do they control?

Tags: block-producer, bp

Who controls the NYC block producer? And how much eos do they control? And how were they nominated in the first place?

Comment: Did something regarding this account happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOS New York is a self-funded and self-owned Block Producer. Our ownership disclosure can be found [here](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/eos-new-york-ownership-disclosure-and-corporate-structure). The amount of EOS we own can be found in our *eosnewyorkio* account on-chain [here](https://bloks.io/account/eosnewyorkio). Block Producers aren't actually nominated by others but by registering on-chain via `regproducer`.

```
./cleos.sh push action eosio regproducer '["account", "pub-key", "URL", "country-code"]' -p accountname
```

You can check out our [website](http://eosnewyork.io) or [visit us on telegram in our public channel](https://t.me/eosnewyorkchat) for more information. We're happy to answer any questions you may have.

This account is managed by Kevin Rose, head of Community for EOS New York. This is why the account is new. Our technical team members have their own individual profiles.

Comment: perhaps more of a meta question... but why is this downvoted to -5? it just answers the question

Comment: I am also not sure why this got -5 downvotes. Maybe because the account is quite fresh and there is no confirmation that this is really someone of EOS NY?